# How to connect Cassandra with Spark using Scala in windows

Tags: windows, scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I am trying to connect Spark and Cassandra using Scala as described here 
http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/kindling-an-introduction-to-spark-with-cassandra/ 
I am facing errors in the steps under the heading:

"To load the connector into the Spark Shell:"

val test_spark_rdd = sc.cassandraTable(“test_spark”, “test”)

***test_spark_rdd.first***
while using above command(Bold)

it shows the error
**Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) java.lang.NullPointerException**

i have uploaded complete stack trace here

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UjGXKifD6chq7-WrHd3GT3LoNcw8GawxAPeOtiEjKvM/edit?usp=sharing

Some rpc settings from the cassandra.YAML file are:

```
rpc_address: localhost 
# rpc_interface: eth1 
# rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6: false 
# port for Thrift to listen for clients on 
rpc_port: 9160
```

**My spark-defaults config file**

```
# Default system properties included when running spark-submit.
# This is useful for setting default environmental settings.

# Example:
# spark.master                     spark://master:7077
# spark.eventLog.enabled           true
# spark.eventLog.dir               hdfs://namenode:8021/directory
#spark.serializer                 org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
#spark.driver.memory              5g
#spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -#Dkey=value -Dnumbers="one two three"
spark.cassandra.connection.host localhost
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
15/08/04 21:24:50 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:873)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.chmod(FileUtil.java:853)
```

Looks like the issue is that the underlying forked executor process failed to start up or do something with the local filesystem. Make sure the default spark directories are accessible by the Executor Process.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me to the right direction and highlighting the relevant area in Stack Trace for me. I finally found my solution here:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.spark.user/11471
Hadoop libraries are required to perform the chmod operations in windows. My solution was in the last post of the above link. Thanks again for the help and getting me out of this issue.

Comment: Ah I 'm glad you found your solution! You are allowed to add it as an additional answer to this question and accept your own answer ;) I would be pleased to +1 it